# Getting the correct date and set notification ios

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to set repeating notifications for every saturday and sunday but for some reason the date is coming out wrong.This is my code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth |NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth;
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateComponents *dt = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
comps.hour   = hour;
comps.minute = [[goal.reminderTimeInfo valueForKey:@"minutes"] intValue];
[dt setMonth:[comps month]];
[dt setYear:[comps year]];
[dt setWeekOfMonth:[comps weekOfMonth]];
comps.weekday = 1;  //Sunday
[dt setWeekday:[comps weekday]];

NSDate *sundayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dt];
```

Its suppose to give out

```
2015-07-05 19:00:00 +0000
```

but its giving

```
2015-07-04 19:00:00 +0000
```

And if give the local notification a particular date.For example its sunday.Will it fire every sunday?

Comment: It will fire at 2015-07-04 19:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not change the hour and the minutes for dt but for comps.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth |NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *dt = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

    dt.hour   = 19;
    dt.minute = 00;
    [dt setMonth:[comps month]];
    [dt setYear:[comps year]];
    [dt setWeekOfMonth:[comps weekOfMonth]];
    [dt setWeekday:1];

    NSDate *sundayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dt];
```